# How to use NSWritingDirectionAttributeName in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How to use NSWritingDirectionAttributeName in swift?

I have this code in Obj-c:

```
attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontAwesomeFontOfSize:24], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:kHJColorIcon, NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:@[@(NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft | NSTextWritingDirectionOverride)]}];
```

which is working great!

Now I need to use the same code in another place but in swift language.

I tried several ways but I get errors.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName` expects numeric values so use the raw values

```
[NSWritingDirectionAttributeName : [NSWritingDirection.LeftToRight.rawValue | NSTextWritingDirection.Override.rawValue]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The key `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName` need the Numeric value so use in addition of `rawValue` on your function, try this

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Karthik Test",
                 attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24),
                              NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:[NSWritingDirection.RightToLeft.rawValue |
                                                               NSTextWritingDirection.Override.rawValue]])
```